# how do i use Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitMagicNumbers

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-critic

I want to use module Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitMagicNumbers to check for **magic numbers only** in a .C file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Perl::Critic;

open(my $FILE, "< test.c") or die $!;
my $critic = Perl::Critic->new(); 
my @violations = $critic->critique($FILE);
print @violations;

close($FILE);
```

If I Use Perl::Critic, I get error
Can't parse code: Unknown error parsing Perl document

If I use Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions::ProhibitMagicNumbers, I get error
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Perl::Critic"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl::Critic parses Perl, not C.